# Wick Contractions; help with a piece of code

Tags: function-construction, code-review, code-request

An alternative title to this thread could be, understanding another person's code.

A few years back there was a workshop on Mathematica and applications to theoretical physics; if you want I can include the link.

From that workshop, I found the following example which is relative to what I would like to do. I am including a screenshot to show you the notebook and the result and further below I am attaching the actual code.

Here it is. This is the example I am interested in.

[image: Wick Contractions]

It gives a very nice and useful result, and I thought I could try to run the notebook, understand it, maybe tweak it a little bit if necessary, and then work out some other cases of interest.

However when I run the notebook, without making any changes, this is what I get back.

[image: Output of the above]

Unfortunately, I haven't attended the workshop, as I was an undergraduate student back then.

The notebook was created in an earlier version of Mathematica. That much I know.

The question is, how can I run the notebook and get the result as shown in the first picture? What is messing the code up? Any piece of information is more than welcome.

This is the actual code.

```
wick[X_Times] := Block[{list = List @@ X}, \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 2\), \(Length[
      list]\)]\(\[LeftAngleBracket]list[[1]], 
      list[[n]]\[RightAngleBracket]\ wickT[
      Times @@ Drop[Drop[list, {n}], 1]]\)\)];
wick[1] = 1;

Table[o[k] = 
   y[k][A] y[k][B] \[Phi][A][i, j][x[k]] \[Phi][B][j, i][
      x[k]] /. {A -> Unique[A], B -> Unique[B], i -> Unique[i], 
     j -> Unique[j]}, {k, 4}];

Attributes[\[Delta]] = {Orderless};
Attributes[\[CapitalDelta]] = {Orderless};

prop[\[Phi][I_][i_, j_][x_], \[Phi][J_][k_, l_][x_]] = 0;
prop[\[Phi][I_][i_, j_][x_], \[Phi][J_][k_, l_][
    y_]] := \[CapitalDelta][I, J] \[Delta][i, l] \[Delta][k, j] Sort@
    G[x, y];

indices = {\[CapitalDelta][a_, b_]^2 :> 6, \[CapitalDelta][a_, a_] :> 
    6, y[i_][a_] y[j_][a_] :> Subscript[y, i, 
    j], \[CapitalDelta][a_, b_] c_ :> (c /. a -> b) /; ! FreeQ[c, a], 
   G[x[i_], x[j_]] :> 1/(
    2 Subscript[x, i, j]^2), \[Delta][a_, 
     b_]^2 :> \[DoubleStruckCapitalN], \[Delta][a_, 
     a_] :> \[DoubleStruckCapitalN], \[Delta][a_, 
      b_] c_ :> (c /. a -> b) /; ! FreeQ[c, a]};

precontractions = 
  towick[o[1] o[2] o[3] o[4] // Expand] //. 
     towick[a_ b_] :> a towick[b] /; FreeQ[a, \[Phi]] /. 
    towick -> wick // Expand;

G4 = precontractions /. AngleBracket -> prop //. indices // 
  Collect[#, \[DoubleStruckCapitalN], FullSimplify] &
```

I am not quite sure, but I think that what messes up the result is the following command

```
Table[o[k] = 
  y[k][A] y[k][B] \[Phi][A][i, j][x[k]] \[Phi][B][j, i][x[k]] /. {A ->
      Unique[A], B -> Unique[B], i -> Unique[i], j -> Unique[j]}, {k, 
  4}]
```

And I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: After the comments, the original piece of code

From [this link](http://msstp.org/?q=node/286) it is this one: P. Vieira, Gamma Matrices and Wick Contractions lecture.nb

Edit: I just realised that I did not give any info on the background of all this. So, a bit of background knowledge.

Consider operators of the form

$$\mathcal{O}_{p}(x,y) = y^{R_1} \cdots y^{R_p} tr(\phi_{R_1}(x) \cdots \phi_{R_p}(x)) $$

I want to study four-point functions, which generically can be written as

$$ <p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4> = \mathcal{O}_{p_1}(x_1,y_1) \mathcal{O}_{p_2}(x_2,y_2) \mathcal{O}_{p_3}(x_3,y_3) \mathcal{O}_{p_4}(x_4,y_4) $$

Each operator is a collection of some number of fields, $\phi$.

So, the above four-point function just contracts all possible combinations and then from the normalisation of the trace which gives back just $\delta$ of Kronecker. More specifically, see the example below as well,

$$(T^a)^i_j (T^a)^k_l = \delta_{il} \delta_{jk}$$

An easy example.

Set $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4=1$ and examine

$$<1111> = <Tr(\phi^i _i) Tr(\phi^j _j) Tr(\phi^m _m) Tr(\phi^n _n)> \\
= \phi^a \phi^b \phi^c \phi^d (T^a)^i_i (T^b)^j_j (T^c)^k_k (T^d)^l_l \\
= \delta ^i_i \delta ^j_j \delta ^k_k \delta ^l_l = N^2$$

In this case, it is easy as each operator consists of only one field with contracts with itself.

What I would like, is to write a function that will perform this procedure for me. That is write something like $function[2,2,4,5]$ and perform the contractions as explained above, where each of the numbers denotes the number of fields $\phi$.

I hope this is a helpful edit.

If you need a less trivial example for clarification, please let me know.

Comment: If there is a link to the original notebook, please put it in the question.

Comment: From this link it is this one: P. Vieira, Gamma Matrices and Wick Contractions lecture.nb 
http://msstp.org/?q=node/286

Comment: The commands of the code are exactly the ones I gave in the end. I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/169704/edit) to include that.

Comment: @J.M.  Done. Can you explain to me what did I do wrong? I said it's another person's code and I included screenshots of the things that I don't understand and the original code. I am not trying to be offensive, I actually don't understand what's wrong on my behalf. Cheers!!!

Comment: Nono, after including the link in the question itself, you're all good. It's just that I'm doing other stuff at the moment. I'll look later unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought I broke some rules, this is why I asked. Thanks @J.M.

Comment: In your definition of the wick[] function at the top of your Notebook[], the function wickT[] is undefined, hence the output you get...